# Python, Read both end of the line characters [CR][LF]

Tags: python, string, special-characters

For python in windows environment 
I have a log file that uses [CR][LF] as end of the line indication.

But python will only read the [LF] char (\x0A) as '\n' 
[CR] or'\x0d' is somehow ignored. Len() of the read string is reduced by 1 due to this.

Is there a universal/local setting somewhere I can tell python to avoid doing that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 2, `open` the file in binary mode to avoid line ending translation:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
```

In Python 3, binary mode does a lot more than just disable line ending translation (it also means reading `bytes` instead of `str`), so instead you use [the `newline` keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) to disable line ending translation (by passing the empty string):

```
with open(filename, newline='') as f:
```

Comment: @MarkRansom: No, they just disable the line ending translation. I believe binary mode on Python 2 considers `\n` to be the only line break character, while on Python 3, `newline=''` means that universal newlines mode is used to _recognize_ line breaks (so any of the common line break standards counts as a line break), but leaves them untranslated (you get back the original characters, whatever they were).